# How to change current working directory within a bash script on Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos, bash, shell

I'm struggling with a little problem, I never wrote a bash script before and it may be a little thing for someone who knows how it's done correctly.

I have the following folder structure (cannot be changed):

```
MyApp.app
   |_Contents
       |_Java
           |_MyApp.jar
       |_MacOS
           |_launch.sh
```

The **launch.sh** script should start the MyApp.jar executable and currently looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_DIR=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")/../Java"; pwd)
exec "$SCRIPT_DIR/jre/bin/java" -Xms256m -XX:PermSize=64m -jar "MyApp.jar"
```

When starting the launch.sh script, the second line should change the current working directory from **MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS** to **MyApp.app/Contents/Java** in order to call subsequently *java -jar MyApp.jar* (3rd line) with its correct root directory as working directory...

But as soon as the MyApp.jar starts, I print out the current working directory within my Java application with:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

... and it prints out the directory of the launch.sh script, namely **MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS** instead of **MyApp.app/Contents/Java**.

Any ideas how to properly change the directory within the bash scripts are highly appreciated : ) ... ?!

Comment: Your `cd` command is in a sub-shell, so it only affects that sub-shell. You need to run it directly in the script if you want it to change the main shell's working directory.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the reply. How could this be done within the script? I am sorry, but I am an absolute noob when it comes to scripting...

Comment: Use `cd`, but at the "top level" of the script. You're executing cd in a new scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to do it like this:

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")/../Java"
SCRIPT_DIR=$(pwd)
```

Comment: you are welcome), the explanation why it didn't work before in the first comment under your question

Comment: okay that's fine :) I'll definitely have to hang into bash scripting asap... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could always work with the cd command (change directory). But a more optimal solution, **if** you had to change directories, may be using the `pushd` & `popd` commands to build a stack.

In this case scenario you could hardcode the file path(s) that the script will have to navigate to during execution :

```
_java=/Applications/MyApp.app/_Contents/_Java;
```

Then using pushd and popd (push directory onto stack, pop directory off of stack) :

```
# Currently in /Applications/MyApp.app/_Contents/_MacOS/
pushd $_java;

# Do what you have to do in the _Java working directory (./ = current working directory)
exec "./jre/bin/java" -Xms256m -XX:PermSize=64m -jar "MyApp.jar";

# Print the working directory and return to bottom of stack
pwd; popd;
```

Nothing against the usage of cd, but `pushd` & `popd` answer the question as well and are more flexible than cd in some situations, especially when you really **have** to traverse a file hierarchy on several occasions during execution. for more information `man pushd`, `man popd`, google or related articles such as : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77077/how-do-i-use-pushd-and-popd-commands

Besides that, even for day-to-day usage, cd is great, but in my case I always move around and it's nice to be in my **/Library/LaunchDaemons/** and to simply `pushd ~/Documents/Scripts/`; `vim bashp0rn.sh`; `popd`; and back in **/Library/LaunchDaemons/** to load & launch (`launchctl`).

**Now**, with that said, you don't have to change to your apps working directory in order to launch the application :

> *... in order to call subsequently java -jar MyApp.jar (3rd line) with its correct root directory as working directory ...*

If that is your sole requirement **&&** if that is your *requirement* because in this case you are trying to complete the path by assigning `pwd`'s output to `$SCRIPT_DIR`, then I would suggest hardcoding the full path and using the `eval` command instead as such :

```
#!/bin/bash

app='/Applications/MyApp.app/_Contents/_Java/jre/bin/java -Xms256m -XX:PermSize=64m -jar "MyApp.jar"';
```

Now from anywhere in the file hierarchy you can evaluate the variable :

```
eval $app;
```